# Log lines formatting

Tags: php, class, logging, psr-3

I have a problem with implementation of logging system based on PSR-3 standards (and interfaces/classes delivered with it - https://github.com/php-fig/log).

I have created some classes extending PSR-3: logger, which uses adapters to do actual logging (logger class stores adapter instance and calls log() method in it) and I came to file adapter (adapter that writes log messages into file(s)) and I'm looking for some way to implement custom log line formats. I mean that I could log messages as

`[01/01/2013 12:00:00] NOTICE: Log message content\n`

as well as

`user: Log message content (NOTICE) ~ 01-01-2013`

(complete custom order and contents)

Also, I would like to create separate class for that.

Is there any way to do it in very get-at-able way, so others (even low-skilled phpers) won't have problem with changing this?

Comment: No matter how "get-at-able" you write it, people will find a way to screw it up. Worrying about low-skill coders reading your code is a waste of time.

Comment: Okay, so I was thinking about something like an array of elements (as key => value) and message format as something like '[{date}] {level}: {message}\n'. Message string would replace '{message}' tag, log level '{level}' tag, and the rest would be custom. Also for dynamic values (like date) i would have to check if value is callable. Do you think it is good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is mainstream, but have you looked at [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/)

You could implement `HandlerInterface` instead of `LoggerInterface`. Formatting would be solved by Monolog using your pattern.

This solution is also better as you can use ONE Logger and many Handlers in Monolog.

There is one downside/upside (you decide): you have to implement your level logging in the handler, which might be a bit ugly.